# GTK+ 3.0 C++ The same code works/crashes, depending on situation

Tags: c++, gtk

I got another problem with GTK. There is function `programClose()` which can be called by multiple ways:

```
// File->Quit
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit), "activate", G_CALLBACK(programClose), &data);
// User closed app by clicking red X mark on title bar
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(programClose), &data);
```

`programClose()` looks like that:

```
void programClose(GtkMenuItem *quit, fileData *data)
{
    if(data->isSaved != true)
    {
       showSaveFileDialog(NULL, data);
    }
}
```

And then in `showSaveFileDialog()`:

```
void showSaveFileDialog(GtkMenuItem *saveFile, fileData *data)
{
    cout << data->someBool; // ok
    cout << data->someString; // crashes here
}
```

I tried making another function for closing app by clicking X, but that did not help:

`void programClose(GtkWindow *window, fileData *data)`

Any sugestions?

edit:

Lol, forgot to mention that everything is fine when user closes app by clicking file->quit, program crashes only when clicking the red X mark

---

Ok I fixed it myself. The problem was I forgot about callback functions signatures. So I created wrapper function for closing program by clicking red X:

```
void programCloseByX(GtkWindow *window, GdkEvent *event, fileData *data)
{
    programClose(NULL, data);
}
```

Comment: What's with all the pointers? Either way your example is incomplete, and can probably be solved using a debugger anyway.

Comment: I forgot to add important information, edited my question. And yes I simplified the code, but it shows the problem.

Comment: You "simplified" it to an extend that nobody except for you can debug it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.